# How to get current post ID in Contact Form 7 wpcf7_before_send_mail hook action

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, email, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm trying to handle the CF7 data before send and update the current post custom field using ACF function but I'm unable to get the current post ID the form is send from. I've also tried getting the ID from global $post variable and get_queried_object_id() but it didn't work either.

Any idea how can I get the ID of the post the form was send from?

```
function dv_wpcf7_handle_form_data($wpcf7)
{
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ($submission) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }

    // Check for ID of specific WPCF7 form
    if ($wpcf7->id() == 128) {
        $number_order = $posted_data['customer-number'];
        $number_current_value = get_field('trip_available_seats', get_the_ID()); // passing the ID to function doesn't work
        $number_new_value = $number_current_value - $number_order;

        if ($number_new_value >= 0) {
            update_field('trip_available_seats', $number_new_value, get_the_ID());
        } else {
            $error = true;
            $err_msg = 'Error message...';
        }
    }

    if (isset($error) && $error === true) {
        $msgs = $wpcf7->prop('messages');
        $msgs['mail_sent_ok'] = $err_msg;
        $wpcf7->set_properties(array('messages' => $msgs));
        add_filter('wpcf7_skip_mail', 'abort_mail_sending');
    }

    return $wpcf7;
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'dv_wpcf7_handle_form_data');

function abort_mail_sending($contact_form)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to [a backwards-incompatible change](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/critical-issue-with-5-2/#post-13138516) in version 5.2, you can no longer retrieve the form's meta data using `get_posted_data()`.

Instead, you can use the `id` value in the array returned by `get_current()`:

```
$contact_form = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
$contact_form_id = $contact_form -> id;
```

Comment: That would return the form ID not the "post" ID that OP has asked.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the post ID from array variable `$posted_data` the form was send from

```
  if ($submission) {
       $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
       print_r($posted_data)
  }
```

if you do a `print_r` on it you will get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [_wpcf7] => 20
    [_wpcf7_version] => 5.1.6
    [_wpcf7_locale] => en_US
    [_wpcf7_unit_tag] => wpcf7-f20-p22-o1
    [_wpcf7_container_post] => 22  **//This is what you want.**
    [your-name] => Jon Doe
    [your-email] => test@test.com
    [your-subject] => subject
    [your-message] => message
)
```

Edit:

Since CF7 **version 5.2** the correct way to get the "**post**" ID to which the contact form is tied to is:

```
if ($submission) {
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

That would return something like this:

```
Array
(
    [_wpcf7] => 119 **//This is the "contact form" ID. But one should get that using WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current(); method **
    [_wpcf7_version] => 5.2.1
    [_wpcf7_locale] => en_US
    [_wpcf7_unit_tag] => wpcf7-f119-p120-o1
    [_wpcf7_container_post] => 120 **//This is the "post" ID**
    [_wpcf7_posted_data_hash] => 
    [your-name] => Jon
    [your-email] => Doe
    [your-subject] => Test
    [your-message] => Test
)
```

Comment: Due to a breaking change in 5.2, `get_posted_data` no longer returns any meta data. See below for an alternative answer.

Comment: That's right. since 5.2 `get_posted_data` would not return all fields, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Found out you can get the container post ID with `$_POST['_wpcf7_container_post'])`

Comment: works great from functions.php

Answer (score 2):

if you prefer to retrieve the value from wpcf7 instead of the `$_POST` array, you can use the following. this is similar to how to retrieve the posted data. just use `get_meta` instead of `get_posted_data`:

```
$submission = WPCF7_Submission :: get_instance();
$submission->get_meta('container_post_id');
```